# Can not check internet connection on Cordova App

Tags: android, cordova, networking

I am trying check the users internet connection in my Cordova app to tell them if they do not have an internet connection that they need to have one. I found and installed this plugin https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-network-information after I installed it, I went into my main html page to add in this JS code but I do not get any results. What can I be doing wrong? I have 2 different examples that I have tried with no luck below along with my android-manifest. I have only done what I described above and do now know were else to go. I ran a log-cat but could not find any useful information from it. Is there another way to check an internet connection other than this which can be easier? Any help would be awesome!

```
function checkConnection()
{
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
    var networkState = navigator.connection.type;

    var states = {};
    states[Connection.UNKNOWN]  = 'Unknown connection';
    states[Connection.ETHERNET] = 'Ethernet connection';
    states[Connection.WIFI]     = 'WiFi connection';
    states[Connection.CELL_2G]  = 'Cell 2G connection';
    states[Connection.CELL_3G]  = 'Cell 3G connection';
    states[Connection.CELL_4G]  = 'Cell 4G connection';
    states[Connection.CELL]     = 'Cell generic connection';
    states[Connection.NONE]     = 'No network connection';

    alert('Connection type: ' + states[networkState]);

    });
}

checkConnection();

if(states[networkState] == "Unknown connection")
{
   //output saying the user needs an internet connection
}

</script>
```

I have also tried....

```
    <script>

    document.addEventListener("offline", onOffline, false);

    function onOffline() {
        // Output saying Your internet connection is gone. Connect again
    }
</script>
```

I use these permissions

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to see if your user is connected to the internet is using the Online and Offline event. I made a working example, although your implementation is nearly correct:

```
function onDeviceReady() {
    document.addEventListener("offline", onOffline, false);
    document.addEventListener("online", onOnline, false);
}

function onOffline() {
    alert("Offline");
}

function onOnline() {
    alert("Online");
}
```

Several things to notice:

1. Take care that the EventListeners are added after deviceReady fired! In my example I'm doing this with following line:

`document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, false);`

2. Watch out with inline javascript code: If you are using a Content Security Policy or CSP, this might prevent inline javascript code from executing, if you haven't set the 'unsafe-inline' directive. In Chrome you will see a error like this in your javascript console:

> Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-ZJzCdAlcRvBg/CUgBlBR0EJlHtXyQ/rPspGdZwNhwlw='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution. Note also that 'script-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

Instead of using inline javascript, you should create a javascript file for youe code and reference it in your html.

Comment: Thank you! I guess my problem was that I was trying to run my script without the app being ready. Thank you again!